# Compilation of pictures of SO Meetup Day

Tags: discussion

Where can I find a compilation of photos/videos from the meetups ?
I was just wondering for those of us that did not get the chance to go to the meetup and wanted to see how the event played out.
Guess one can use the pictures for promotion for the next meetup in a year (if there is one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some pictures from the Mountain View, CA meetup (I did not take them):

http://www.flickr.com/photos/61596670@N08/sets/72157626327465633/with/5599261735/

Comment: MOAR CAPSHUNZ!!!11!

Answer (score 1):

Well I can speak of the Montreal event one a little bit. It was organized pretty much at the last minute (the place got confirmed April 6th in the afternoon) and there was 3 of us that showed up.

We pretty much ended up chatting from 7PM to 10PM about various subject of programming and a little bit about Stack Overflow. Nobody brought a camera, so there wasn't any photo taken. It was still a nice event and I will try to do some publicity for the one next year so that we get more people to come.

I know you asked for photos, but words are worth a thousand pictures.*

<sup>* I know it's not the right expression :p</sup>